# Windows 11 AWS CDK: Cannot find module '@aws-cdk/core'

Tags: .net, typescript, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-cdk

I have a C# .NET 6.0 AWS Serverless (SAM) Lambda application built with Visual Studio 2022.  I want to utilize the AWS CDK within it to build/deploy the infrastructure.

Our DevOps department insists that CDK code be written in Typescript rather than C#.  So I have added a `cdk` folder inside my serverless project's folder and have added a Typescript file to it (as described in this instructional article: https://milangatyas.com/Blog/Detail/1/managing-net-core-aws-lambda-with-typescript).

I have also installed all of the needed `npm` packages, ensured that I'm on Node 18, and ensured that I'm using the latest version of the CDK.

And yet, I'm seeing the error `Cannot find module '@aws-cdk/core'` on the following `import` statement at the top of my Typescript file:

`import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');`

My `package.json` file at the same directory level looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.204.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.204.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the dependencies are there.  In addition, my `node_modules` folder contains the `@aws-cdk` folder in addition to the `core` subfolder underneath it.

Here is what my project folder structure looks like:

[image]

Someone please tell me why am I getting this error - and, how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your `cdk.json` located and what's in it?

Comment: Also - note that CDK v1 has reached end of life - consider using CDK v2 instead.

Comment: @gshpychka thanks for the tip.  Missing `cdk.json` was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, since I had created the Typescript components and installed the `npm` packages manually instead of via `cdk init`, the required `cdk.json` file was missing.  I purged my `cdk` folder and ran `cdk init` which fixed the issue.